How do I use css-loaders in vue3?
I imported css-loaders into my vue project, but I'm getting these warnings. I would greatly appreciate  assistance with this.
I did try googling to figure out how to use webkit mask in vue3 but I did'nt get any helpful results

Adding the warnings you've gotten will be nice. Also, how to use webkit mask in vue3 did you mean CSS -webkit-mask property?

Sorry, I thought I attached a screenshot. Yes, the CSS -webkit-mask property is what I was referring to and the warning messages I'm getting is,
"message": "Also define the standard property 'mask' for compatibility",

It seems you only define -webkit prefixed mask-* properties, try to add unprefixed properties. Attention, some -webkit prefixed properties, such as -webkit-mask-composite, have different keywords from the unprefixed ones. You can check the notes in the Browser compatibility section of MDN document. e.g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-composite#browser_compatibility

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
